# Track Members Login Database Design

Tags: asp.net, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008, database-design

```
CREATE TABLE Member
(
    memberID  - PK 
    memberName
        .
        .
    dateCreated
);

CREATE TABLE TrackLogin
(
    memberID - PK and FK
    lastLogin
);
```

TrackLogin will help me know when this member last time has logged in. Any new record inserted in Member table, a new record also will automatically be inserted in TrackLogin.

lastLogin will have a default value (default time and date). Any logins occur, i will update the row to the latest login which will override the default.

Member and TrackLogin is one to one relationship.

I didn't want to put lastLogin in Member table since there trigger is tied to member table and lastLogin has nothing to do with it.

Is this design ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lastLogin` is an atrribute of a `Member`, so it belongs there.  Breaking out is just extra join complexity (IMO).

To prevent the existing trigger from firing, use [UPDATE(column)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) in the trigger to ignore changes to that column.

Comment: I broke it because any update/change in Member, will cause a trigger to fire and move the last changed data into a special History table, so if i put lastLogin in Member, then everytime a user logs in, a member record will be copied in History table which is not effective because the History is only used when user changes memberName, password, email, columns related to registration.

Comment: @user311509 : use update(columnname) in the trigger to ignore changes to that column: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would use TrackLogin table to insert a new record (MemberID and LoginDate) everytime a member login. Then you will have a nice member login activity report instead of only their last login. I had a requirement where the users just need last login date. But then they wanted a login activity report.